# TableView item should load an other TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For uni I have to write a little application and the idea is to create a little formula collection. The concept is to have a category list and after you have chosen the category you receive a list of formulas. After you have chosen your desired formula you get the view of the formula calculator.

I'm struggling to have the first `UITableViewController` load another `UITableViewController`. I edited the storyboard so in my mind it should work but it doesn't. The error it gives me is also not helping at all:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

How am I supposed to achieve this?

My `MasterViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailViewController: FormulaListViewController? = nil
    var categoryList = TestData.sharedInstance.categoryList


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? FormulaListViewController
        }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView .reloadData()
        for category in categoryList {
            print(category)
        }

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }



    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showForumlaList" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = categoryList[indexPath.row]
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! FormulaListViewController
                controller.category = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categoryList.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let object = categoryList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            categoryList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }
}
```

The `FormulaListViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class FormulaListViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!

    var category: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        categoryLabel.text = category
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        categoryLabel.text = category
    }

    var detailItem: String? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
        }
    }
}
```

The error comes from the `AppDelegate`:
Specifically this line: `navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem`

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
        let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
        splitViewController.delegate = self
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // MARK: - Split view

    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
        guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? FormulaListViewController else { return false }
        if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
            // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Mockups of the project:

Home screen: https://snag.gy/WTECxZ.jpg

User chose "Wasserbau" he'll get a list of formulas: https://snag.gy/2mWoEB.jpg

User then chose "Fliessformel": https://snag.gy/D3h5L2.jpg

As I can't really share my storyboard I also uploaded the whole project: https://cloud.aintevenmad.ch/index.php/s/QakGibkAXfmKDxp

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which line is causing the issue?

Comment: Yes which line causing the issue ??

Comment: I've added the source of the issue in the initial post.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot what exactly UI you want to achieve?

Comment: I've added mockups and comments of the UI in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change the structure of your project. Add the UITableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in your `MasterViewController`.

In this `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, write the navigation code.